# Mapreduce example for reading ORC file

Tags: mapreduce, hive, orc

I created a mapreduce code that analyse some files. But some files  was created from Hive and they are in ORC type.

Its possible analyse this ORC file like a Texfile? And the output of mapreduce be a Text type?

tks

Answer (score 1):

what you need is InputFormat OrcNewInputFormat or OrcInputFormat.

```
job.setInputFormatClass(OrcNewInputFormat.class);
```

Then you need a Typestruct, which describes the schema of your table (most likely in your mapper)

```
private final String ts = "struct<" +
        "recordId:bigint," +
        "name:string," +
        "language:string>";   

private final StructTypeInfo ti = (StructTypeInfo) TypeInfoUtils.getTypeInfoFromTypeString(ts);
```

You can get the type information and column names like this

```
List<TypeInfo> type_lst = ti.getAllStructFieldTypeInfos();
List<String> field_lst = ti.getAllStructFieldNames();
```

Next you need a StructObjectInspector to access the fields of your ORC file

```
    StructObjectInspector soi;
    Properties properties = new Properties();

    properties.setProperty("columns.typtes", ts);
    serde.initialize(context.getConfiguration(), properties);

    try {
        obj = serde.deserialize(value);
        soi = (StructObjectInspector)serde.getObjectInspector();
        value_lst = soi.getStructFieldsDataAsList(obj);
    } catch (SerDeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

now you can access the fields of your File like this

```
        rowId = value_lst.get(0).toString();
```

Comment: Hi,I tried it , but doesn't work
SerDe.initialize(context.getConfiguration(), properties); is not recognized.
Error Message: "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method initialize(Configuration, Properties) from the type Deserializer"

Comment: Didn't worked for me as well, rg.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde$OrcSerdeRow cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcStruct. @PhanThomas can you help?